# Exclude a package root from SonarLint?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

How do you exclude all classes in a particular root package in SonarLint?

For example, I want to exclude all classes such as `foo.bar.xxx` and `foo.bar.yyy.zzz`.

I've tried both of these no to avail:

- `sonar.exclusions = /foo/bar/**`
- `sonar.exclusions = **/foo/bar/**`

I'm using the Intellij plugin, but I assume that the syntax would follow the same documented one from here (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the `sonar.exclusions` property is ignored by SonarLint for IntelliJ (and Eclipse too). There's a ticket to add support for that, feel free to vote on it:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-97

Answer (score 1):

Adding the exclusion into the "Test file regular expressions" field works at least for the Eclipse plugin.